# CSS: Hover on 3 stacked images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a photo gallery with stacked photos for each album. When you hover the album I want 1 image to rotate 20 left, one to rotate 20 right so I see bits of 3 images at the same time.

I think the problem is that the hover signals are stuck on the topmost image in the stacks. I'll post what I have tried below. Any ideas? Is it possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Just-CSS: Rotate stacked images on hover</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    }
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    }

img { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
img:hover.green {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
img:hover.blue {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);}

img { border: 4px solid white; }
img.red { background-color: red; }
img.green { background-color: green; }
img.blue { background-color: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="img-stack">
    <li><img class="red" width="100" height="100" src=""></li>
    <li><img class="green" width="100" height="100" src=""></li>
    <li><img class="blue" width="100" height="100" src=""></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I know you can do it with JavaScript but I'm just playing with CSS so please no JavaScript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this:

```
img:hover.green {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
img:hover.blue {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);}
```

to this:

```
ul:hover img.green {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
ul:hover img.blue {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);}
```

Because you can only activate one `:hover` selector at a time (as far as I'm aware), just capture the hover on the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use your ul.img-stack as a wrapper to do it. Trigger the :hover event on the album itself, and not on each picture.

```
ul.img-stack:hover .green {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
ul.img-stack:hover .blue {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img:hover.green {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
```

to

```
img.green:hover {-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);}
```